# Validating and Saving data to SharedPreference

Tags: android

I want to start next activity after validation and I want to save the information in sharedpreferences successfully when i click submit button

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
EditText fullname, contact, emailaddress, address, password, repassword, username;
RadioGroup radiogroup;
Button submits,clear;
Toolbar toolbar;
SearchView  mSearchView;
SharedPreferences pref;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.register);
    pref = getSharedPreferences("myfile", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    fullname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittextfullname);
    contact = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittextcontact);
    emailaddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittextemailaddress);
    address = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittextaddress);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittextpassword);
    repassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittextrepassword);
    username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittextusername);
    radiogroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radiogroup);
    submits = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.Title);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


    submits.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
                final String name = fullname.getText().toString();
                if (!isValidFullname(name)) {
                    fullname.setError("Invalid Name");
                }

                final String number = contact.getText().toString();
                if (!isValidContact(number)) {
                    contact.setError("Invalid Contact");
                }

                final String email = emailaddress.getText().toString();
                if (!isValidEmailaddress(email)) {
                    emailaddress.setError("Invalid Email Address");
                }

                final String addres = address.getText().toString();
                if (!isValidAddress(addres)) {
                    address.setError("Invalid address");
                }
                final String pass = password.getText().toString();
                final String rpassword = repassword.getText().toString();

                if (pass.equals(rpassword) && rpassword.equals(pass)) {
                } else {
                    password.setError("invalid");
                    repassword.setError("invalid");
                }

                final String uname = username.getText().toString();
                if (!isValidUsername(uname)) {
                    username.setError("Invalid Username");
                }
            else {
                    Intent startNewActivity = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, DisplayActivity.class);
                    startActivity(startNewActivity);

                }


           SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
            editor.putString("fullname",name);
            editor.putString("contact",number);
            editor.putString("emailaddress",email);
            editor.putString("address",addres);
            editor.putString("password",pass);
            editor.putString("repassword",rpassword);
            editor.putString("username",uname);
            editor.apply();
            Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, "Save succesful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

    });
     private boolean isValidContact(String number) {
    if (number != null && number.length() == 10) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private boolean isValidEmailaddress(String email) {
    String EMAIL_PATTERN = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
            + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(email);
    return matcher.matches();
}

private boolean isValidAddress(String addres) {
    if (addres != null) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private boolean isValidPassword(String pass) {
    if (pass.equals(repassword) && repassword.equals(pass)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

private boolean isValidUsername(String name) {
    if (name != null && name.length() > 5) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: you forget to add your problem how-to-ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You should just put

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putString("fullname",name);
        editor.putString("contact",number);
        editor.putString("emailaddress",email);
        editor.putString("address",addres);
        editor.putString("password",pass);
        editor.putString("repassword",rpassword);
        editor.putString("username",uname);
        editor.apply();
```

In your

```
else {
                Intent startNewActivity = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, DisplayActivity.class);
                startActivity(startNewActivity);

            }
```

Or do i missunderstand what you want to do ?

Comment: when i click submit button than if validation success than save  in sharedpref file and go to next activity else not